# Use a ModalPopupExtender to display a table and then pass the selected record to the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a search screen on my website which has various parameters. It is possible that many records could be returned, yet the user will only want to see the details of one record. In the case where many records are returned I want to display a modal popwindow with a data grid which will display some of the core fields and then from there the user can select the record they want to see in more detail and it will then close the modal-window and take them back to the main page where additional details are displayed.

I want to know how to pass the data (which will be in a list collection) from my aspx page to the popup window and populate the grid with the information.

I have tried server side but the controls on the popup (i.e. the datagrid) are not initialized. I have been looking but can't find anything on the web which shows how to do this.

Comment: First things first, check my edits, did I make things appear too vastly different than they are? Secondly, would you be open to some other ideas _besides_ a MPE? You're going to need to do a postback anyways, so why not use two controls in two panels and hide/display the appropriate panel based on the workflow step (you're using postback, that's what it's for).

Comment: a little, I have the records in a collection on the aspx page, I then need to  pass these records to the mpe. My main problem is the mpe showing these records. I have tried a simple example (based on Darios suggestion) where I just have a panel on the apsx page with a lable and then try to populate the label with the id of the first record and it does not get set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what you can do:

Add the grid, I usually do it inside a panel

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnStudios" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="gvStudios" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvStudios_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Link the mpe to the panel

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeStudios" runat="server" BehaviorID="mpeStudios"  Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtStudio" PopupControlID="pnStudios">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

In your case you can leave the TargetControlID empty.

When you want to show it use this

```
gvStudios.DataSource = studios;
gvStudios.DataBind();
mpeStudios.Show();
```

Where studios is a list collection.

In the OnSelectedIndexChanged of the grid you can get the selected value and get the details so you can show them in your main page, the mpe will close automatically when a postback is done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That didnt work, like in my comment above I tried it with a grid but also with a simple label on the mpe to just show the id of the first record in the list. This also did not work, effectively the label would not be refreshed, I guess this is because it has not been posted back to the server. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Put the grid inside an updatepanel, maybe that will solve it.